# clearInterval does not reset

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to make a function that calculate the time progress of a song from Spotify but I am stuck on the clearInterval function. The problem is that the timer just keeps speeding up after i try to reset it. I am using Reactjs

First run intervalToTick is 1.6 seconds but if i run the function again it is double as fast and keeps getting faster for every reset (works first time)

My solution was since I use mobX was to add the `myTimer` as a @observable in the store and then proceed with the answer below

```js
const ticker = function() {
  if (store.timer < 100) {
    store.addToTimer() //mobX store action to add 1+ to the store.timer
  }

};

function progress() {
  store.timer = 0
  let time = Moment()
  let songEnd = Moment().add(1, "minutes")
  const durationToFinnish = Moment.duration(songEnd.diff(time));
  const intervalToTick = 100000 / durationToFinnish.asMilliseconds()

  //Dumb to have it 2 times but cant figure of another way
  var myTimer = window.setInterval(ticker, intervalToTick * 1000);
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = window.setInterval(ticker, intervalToTick * 1000);
}
```

```html
<div className={classes.progressBar} id="progress">
  <div className={classes.innerProgressBar}>
    <span onClick={progress}>{store.timer}%</span><br></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the timer variable have a higher scope so it can be accessed from both `progress` and `ticker` and you need to clear the interval if there's one already running so that you can't have multiple intervals running simultaneously:

```js
var myTimer = null; // Declared here so it can be used in both functions

const ticker = function () {
  if(store.timer < 100){
    store.addToTimer() //mobX store action to add 1+ to the store.timer
  }      
};

function progress() {        
  store.timer = 0
  let time = Moment()
  let songEnd = Moment().add(1, "minutes")
  const durationToFinnish = Moment.duration(songEnd.diff(time));
  const intervalToTick = 100000 / durationToFinnish.asMilliseconds()  
  // Check to see if there is already a timer running
  if(myTimer){
    clearInterval(myTimer); // Stop the interval   
  }
  myTimer = setInterval(ticker, intervalToTick * 1000);    
}
```

```html
<div className={classes.progressBar} id="progress">
            <div className={classes.innerProgressBar}>
                <span onClick={progress}>{store.timer}%</span><br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have tried that to and still have the same problem. I cant have the clearInterval(myTimer) in the ticker function since i want it to continue ticking untill progress function is run again

Comment: It is still ticking faster for every time the progress function is run. But how? is seems so strange. Link to a video https://i.gyazo.com/d5679765fcc18b5c776da1cfce76c4ef.mp4

Comment: @pat Double-check your implementation. If you use the code I've shown (and I updated it again for simplification), there's no way a second timer can run.

Comment: I added the "myTimer" to the mobX store as a @observable variable and then it worked! But i dont know how it didnt work to declare it at the top as you did